# Circular Loop auto Scroll Animation in React Native

Tags: react-native, loops, animation

I have a use case where there are "n" JSX objects of different size and are placed horizontal with use of `{flex-direction: "row"}`.

My requirement is to auto scroll these n objects in a circular loop i.e., I want the 1st JSX object to reappear after nth JSX object.

Note: I don't want loop to be rendering one object after the other.

I have tried using "react-native-looped-carousel" library but it's rendering only one object at a time and then scrolling.

Comment: `I don't want loop to be rendering one object after the other.` What does that mean?

Comment: @DavidScholz, I mean that there can be multiple jsx objects visible on display based on screen size of user, have seen online about some solutions where they are suggesting some approaches which renders one object at a time and it scrolls

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a custom thing you might want to create a carousel like this:

- create three view elements
- cycle values through these three views (0 - previous, 1 - current, 2 - next)
- when you switch to the next item (2 becomes 1), replace content in next item (2) by the content you need.

You can also take a look `react-native-reanimated-carousel`, it has a `loop` property, seems to do what you want.